# Is there an way to run a While loop 60 times a second?

Tags: python, while-loop, frame-rate

I'm trying to create a game in Tkinter, and I want to have a While loop run only x times a second. Evenly spaced.

I have tried dividing 1 by X and using the time module to wait that amount. But it didn't run it 60 times a second, only 50.

```py
def start(self):
        Frame.__init__(self, self.master)
        self.fpLength = 1 / self.fps
        while True:
            # Code here
            time.sleep(self.fpLength)
```

I expect the code to run 60 times a second. But it runs around 55.

Comment: `# Code here` will also take some time... and the `while` statement itself consumes a tiny amount of time.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Yea that makes sense. But I know no other way to do it. Ik that it is possible in pygame, but I am more confident in Tkinter.

Comment: as a first approximation you could measure how long it took to get to the `sleep` statement (using [time.perf_counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter)) in every iteration of the loop and calculate the +/- correct sleep time...

Comment: If you aren't doing it in thread time.sleep() is a bad choice. Event-driven tkinter will freeze.

Comment: You can run it 60 times a second only if the code you want to run takes less that 1/60th of a second.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ohh. It is just a lot of IF statements and running some functions.

Comment: @SebastianSnoer: that doesn't tell me anything. What is important is what those functions do. Do they run in under 1/60th of a second? The number of lines of code doesn't matter, it's what those lines of code do.

Comment: @BryanOakley I can't tell. It is the core game loop and I have no idea how the one using the engine will use it. What would happen if it took more?

Comment: It's simple math. If you try to run something sixty times per second but that "something" takes longer than 1/60th a second, it simply won't run at sixty times a second. Think of the extreme: if the function takes a full second, you can only run it once per second. You can't fit sixty seconds (60 * 1) into a single second.

Comment: @BryanOakley So if it takes more it will maybe just run 56 times a second?

Comment: Yes, it's just basic math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing it in thread (see my comment) you can try something like

```
def start(self):
        Frame.__init__(self, self.master)
        # self.fpLength = 1 / self.fps
        while True:
            # Code here
            clock = time.perf_counter() * 60  #  measer time in 1/60 seconds
            sleep = int(clock) + 1 - clock  #  time till the next 1/60 
            time.sleep(sleep/60)
```

Of cause you can use self.fps instead of constant 60 here, I use it just for more clear comments.

Comment: Is there a way to get a int or a float of how many times(FPS) the while loop ran that second?
PS: Like FPS

Comment: make two variables, cur_frames and cur_second, then in existing while cycle ```if int(time.perf_counter())==cur_second: cur_frames +=1 else: cur_frames=0;cur_second=int(time.perf_counter())``` just before cur_frames=0 you have number of frames in last second, use it as you like